# Munchkin: Tuba of charm loot

Tags: munchkin

If you have the tuba of charm, and you fight multiple monsters, do you take a loot for each monster escaped, or just one for the entire battle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You draw only one treasure total if you manage to flee a battle with multiple monsters.

This question came up in the SJG-forum and was answered by one of the Munchkin editors:

> I'll admit that the wording is unclear, but the INTENT was that you got one Treasure as you fled the combat, no matter how many monsters you fought.

See: http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?t=75522